# How to print element names using XML::Twig

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

Thanks, to this forum i was able to successfully write a perl script to edit xml file. But i would like to print something to the screen. I would like to display the xml contents before and after the change. Please help me out.

**Input XML**

```
<config>
<match_name>Match_20111010</match_name>
<teamA>Alpha_2353523</teamA>
<teamB>Beta_23523523</teamB>
<result>Win</result>
</config>
```

**CODE**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
my $xml = 'config.xml';
my $twig = XML::Twig->new (

    twig_roots => {match => \&edittag,
                   teamA => \&edittag,
                   teamB => \&edittag,
    },
    twig_print_outside_roots => 1,
    );

$twig->parsefile_inplace($xml);



sub edittag {
    my ($twig, $tag) = @_;
    my $text = $tag->text ();
    $text =~ s/\d+/REPLACED/;
    $tag->set_text ($text);
    $twig->flush;

}
```

Comment: Which contents do you want to print, the whole `xml` file? I don't understand what is your expected output and in what way your current code doesn't work.

Comment: I have no issues with code , i just want to print to the standard output screen the xml tag name with the values in it before and after change. something like this.
Not sure how to print just the tag names of the xml file using Twig module.

Comment: I am using parse_inplace to write changes to the xml file. So the print statement under edittag sub are also written into xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `print()` function to `STDOUT`:

```
$twig->print(\*STDOUT);
```

Or to print only the tag name:

```
print STDOUT $tag->name;
```

Comment: Sorry, but the output is kind of clumsy. Is there any option in XML::Twig to extract just the element name. What i want here is 
`print "XML TAG name: Old element value"
print "XML TAG name: new element value"`

Comment: @chidori: How about `print STDOUT $tag->name;`?

Comment: Thanks, that works. Can you please explain what `\*STDOUT` stands for and how does that differ from `STDOUT`.

Comment: @chidori: As I understand, a typeglob is the way to pass a filehandle to a function, and `STDOUT` is a filehandle opened by default in `perl` so I use it directly with the standard `print` function.