# How to rename XML element names, decided at run-time?

Tags: xml, perl, rename, transformation

I've tried a bit myself, search a lot, but could not find a solution how to do that efficiently in Perl (I guess the solution would be somewhat similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/22119220/6607497):

I have some bad XML input files (i.e. it's claimed to conform to a specific XML content model, but the casing of the element names is inconsistent) that I want to fix if necessary.
For that I would have to compare each element name with a list of valid names, and if the bad element name matches a valid element name ignoring the case of the name, then the bad name should be changed to the corresponding valid name.

Like `<Bad>...</Bad>` (wrong case) being converted to `<bad>...</bad>` (correct case).
In reality it's more complex, of course. Also it's not always true that the bad tags use mixed casing, and the good ones use only lower case; it could be any combination...

I have created a list of all valid element names, but I'm missing (e.g.) how to use `XML::Twig` to set a handler for "any node" (wanting to use `set_tag` in the handler to fix the name).

Creating a list of any case permutation of any of the tags would be doable, but it seems inefficient, as only a minor portion of all those possible bad spellings would occur in reality.

## Fancy Example

Here is some fancy fun example:
Assume the valid element names are:

```perl
use constant GOOD_TAGS => qw(ABBA beard Elvis set ZZTop);
```

And the sample bad input looks like this:

```xml
<Set>
  <Beard type="none">
    <elvis />
  </Beard>
  <Beard type="long">
    <ZZtop />
  </Beard>
  <Beard type="mixed">
    <Abba />
  </Beard>
</Set>
```

Then the fixed output should be:

```xml
<set>
  <beard type="none">
    <Elvis />
  </beard>
  <beard type="long">
    <ZZTop />
  </beard>
  <beard type="mixed">
    <ABBA />
  </beard>
</set>
```

I din't know that you can use compiled reguar expressions as hash keys, but it seems to work, so you might assume this starting scenario as well:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use constant GOOD_TAGS => qw(ABBA beard Elvis set ZZTop);
my %fixes;

foreach (GOOD_TAGS) {
    $fixes{qr/^${_}$/i} = $_;
}

my @matchers = keys %fixes;
```

So all elements matching an item in `@matchers` should be renamed to the corresponding hash value.

Comment: Have you tried the sax parser: https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::SAX

Comment: @HåkonHægland No, I did not examine that: Too many XML tools there already (XML::Parser, XML::Twig, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to use XML::Twig to set a handler for "any node"

Use [`_all_`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig#_all_) as key in the handlers defined for [`twig_handlers`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig#twig_handlers) when creating the `XML::Twig` object.

> Creating a list of any case permutation of any of the tags would be doable, but it seems inefficient

Indeed. Instead, I would suggest to normalize the good tags, and check if the normalized tags that you see in the XML match any of the normalized good tags. Here, normalizing can be done by converting to lower case. Something like:

```
my %normalized_good_tags = map { lc($_) => $_ } GOOD_TAGS;
my $bad_tag = "BEaRD";
my $fixed_bad_tag = $normalized_good_tags{lc $bad_tag};
```

Putting it all together, this gives us:

```
use constant GOOD_TAGS => qw(ABBA beard Elvis set ZZTop);
my %normalized_good_tags = map { lc($_) => $_ } GOOD_TAGS;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
  keep_spaces => 1,
  twig_handlers => {
    _all_ => sub {
      my $corrected_tag = $normalized_good_tags{lc $_->tag};
      if (defined $corrected_tag) {
        $_->set_tag($corrected_tag);
      } # else, the tag doesn't need to be changed
    }
  });
$twig->parsefile($xml_file);
$twig->print(1);
```

You could also simplify

```
my $corrected_tag = $normalized_good_tags{lc $_->tag};
if (defined $corrected_tag) {
    $_->set_tag($corrected_tag);
}
```

to

```
$_->set_tag($normalized_good_tags{lc $_->tag} // $_->tag);
```

I don't feel strongly either way, so pick the one you like the most. The shorter one is a bit more expensive (because it will sometimes call `$_->set_tag($_->tag)`), but this might not matter.

Comment: One question: What is the difference between using `_all_` and using`//*`? Isn't is also "every element"?

Answer (score 2):

Here it is also with [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML). It uses [XML::LibXML::Node](https://metacpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/view/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod) to read/set node name.

Go through the nodes and check their names against the good list.  In the given example can compare lowcase node-name against lowcase ("normalized") good names. Since

> In reality it's more complex, of course.

the actual comparison criterion would conform to that reality.  (Levenshtein distance?)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Const::Fast;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = <<'__XML__';
<Set>
  <Beard type="none">
    <elvis />
  </Beard>
  <Beard type="long">
    <ZZtop />
  </Beard>
  <Beard type="mixed">
    <Abba />
  </Beard>
</Set>
__XML__

const my %good      => map { $_ => 1 }     qw(ABBA beard Elvis set ZZTop);
const my %good_norm => map { lc $_ => $_ } keys %good;    

my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_string($xml);

foreach my $node ($doc->findnodes('//*')) {
    my $name = $node->nodeName();

    if ( exists $good_norm{lc $name} and not exists $good{$name} ) {
        $node->setNodeName( $good_norm{lc $name} );
    }   
}

print $doc->toString();
```

Given that all nodes have to be visited (in some way) in order to be checked this is in principle roughly as efficient as it gets.

If the good list has literally *all* node names then it only takes the second test above

```
    if ( not exists $good{$name} ) {
        $node->setNodeName( $good_norm{lc $name} );
    }
```

In reality you may need yet more and/or different tests of course.

Answer (score 1):

Tested out [XML::SAX](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::SAX) parser. Seems like the following should work:

```
use v5.38;

package MySAXHandler;
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use base qw(XML::SAX::Base);
use HTML::Entities ();

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    #my $self = $class->SUPER::new();
    my %args = @_;
    my $self = bless \%args, $class;
    my $output_file = $self->{output_file};
    $self->{good_regex} = join "|", map {quotemeta} @{$self->{good_tags}};
    $self->{tags_seen} = {};
    open (my $fh, ">", $output_file) or die "Could not open file '$output_file': $!";
    $self->{fh} = $fh;
    return bless $self, $class;
}

sub characters {
    my ($self, $content) = @_;
    print {$self->{fh}} HTML::Entities::encode_entities($content->{Data});
}

sub end_document {
  my ($self, $doc) = @_;
  # process document end event
    $self->{fh}->close();
}

sub end_element {
    my ($self, $el) = @_;

    my $tag = $el->{Name};
    $tag = $self->fixup_tag($tag);
    print {$self->{fh}} "</" . $tag . ">"; # process element end event
}

sub find_good_tag {
    my ($self, $tag) = @_;

    for my $key (@{$self->{good_tags}}) {
        if ($tag =~ /$key/i) {
            $self->{tags_seen}{$tag} = $key;
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return undef;
}

sub fixup_tag {
    my ($self, $tag) = @_;
    my %tags_seen = %{$self->{tags_seen}};
    if ($tag =~ /($self->{good_regex})/i) {
        my $good_tag;
        if (exists $tags_seen{$tag}) {
            $good_tag = $tags_seen{$tag};
        }
        else {
            $good_tag = $self->find_good_tag($tag);
        }
        $good_tag = $tag if not defined $good_tag;
        return $good_tag;
    }
    return $tag;
}

sub get_attribute_string {
    my ($self, $attrs) = @_;

    my @attr_pairs = ();
    for my $key (keys %$attrs) {
        my $attr_name = $key =~ s/^\Q{}\E//r;  # TODO: This looks like a bug in XML::SAX ?
        my $attr_value = $attrs->{$key}->{Value};
        my $str = $attr_name . "=" . $attr_value;
        push @attr_pairs, $str;
    }
    my $str = "";
    $str = join " ", @attr_pairs;
    $str = " " . $str if $str ne "";
    return $str;
}

sub start_document {
  my ($self, $doc) = @_;
  # process document start event
}

sub start_element {
    my ($self, $el) = @_;
    # process element start event
    my $tag = $el->{Name};
    my $attrs = $el->{Attributes};
    $tag = $self->fixup_tag($tag);
    my $attr_str = $self->get_attribute_string($attrs);
    print {$self->{fh}} "<${tag}${attr_str}>";
}

package main;
use v5.38;
use XML::SAX;

my @GOOD_TAGS = qw(ABBA beard Elvis set ZZTop);
my $output_file = "output.xml";
my $handler = MySAXHandler->new(output_file => $output_file, good_tags => \@GOOD_TAGS);
my $p = XML::SAX::ParserFactory->parser(Handler => $handler);
$p->parse_file("input.xml");
```

Comment: Re "*XML::SAX parser*", XML::SAX isn't a parser. It's a front end that uses one of many parsers. I'd make sure to have XML::LibXML installed so it doesn't fall back to XML::SAX::PurePerl. (XML::SAX::PurePerl is going to be slow, and it had at least one major issues last time I looked.)

Comment: And if you're going to use XML::LibXML, might as well use its pull parser, XML::LibXML::Reader. I'll see if I can write an example later today.

Comment: hmmm, I can't find a way to output the component XML::LibXML::Reader read, so forget my previous comment.